# Elasticsearch camel end Point

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, apache-camel

Please let me Know how to create consumer for elastic search endpoint using camel.[Consumer code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchEndpoint.java)

I want to create custom elasticsearch consumer as only code for Producer is available [ElasticsearchProducer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/0e871478c05b67cfef10072332ec09979a7f3ca9/components/camel-elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchProducer.java).
For Consumer it is throwing only exception.I want to create my own consumer component as consumer code is throwing only exception and not consuming any thing.

```
public org.apache.camel.Consumer createConsumer(org.apache.camel.Processor processor)
                                     throws Exception

Throws:
    Exception
```

Thanks in advance for the help... :-)

Comment: This might be a place to start: http://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html

Comment: @Ray:- I have already added dependencies in my POM file for elastic search.

Comment: Please add your route definition (and take some time to format your question...)

Answer (score 2):

Camel Elasticsearch component does not support a consumer. How ever if you would like to query elasticsearch by Id, you can do that as follows

```
String json = template.requestBody("elasticsearch://local?operation=GET_BY_ID&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet", "Id");
```

If your requirement is something else, then probably you have to create your own component.

Comment: I have create my own camel component for elastic search , consumer as well as custom producer.. :-)